# find the minimum number of vertices in a directed graph from which the other vertices are reachable

Tags: algorithm, graph, social-networking

In a directed graph i want to call bfs on some of the vertices so that all of the vertices will be met.

(in other words all of the other vertices are reachable from these chosen vertices.)

I want to find the minimum number of such vertices.

Actually this problem arises in social networks when we want to find the minimum number of people to which if we send a message then all of the network members will get that.(suppose that we know when someone gets the message he/she will send that to all of his/her followers.)

Can anyone help?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [mathematics.se]

Comment: This problem can find another application to dictionaries: the minimal set of vertices corresponds to the words that you have to know in order to be able to understand a whole dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the graph without cycle(i.e acyclic graph), it will be easy. All the nodes without incoming edges will be an optimal solution. Since all other nodes should be reachable from one of the nodes.

For the graph with cycle, find [strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) first, then you get a acyclic graph. The method above works again.

Comment: For questioners, can you please explain how they can avoid getting a question put on hold because it can be solved by mathematics without getting it put on hold because it is too broad? It seems to me that a remarkable number of questions fall into one of these two categories.

Comment: Vote up for the reply, zhiwenf. But confused why strongly connected components only? You could have A->B->C which doesn't form a "strongly connected" component?

Comment: For this case, you already have an acyclic graph, you can reach every other node from {A}?